# SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xbd' in file .pyo

Tags: python

I have a python app.pyo and i have this error:

```
  File "RdpConnect.pyo", line 1
SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xbd' in file RdpConnect.pyo on line
2, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for detail
s
```

In normal application this error is really simple to fix, how i can fix ecodec error in **.pyo** file ?

**Attention:** i don't have source code of application

Comment: Which command line do you use to call your application?

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE C:\Users\admin\Desktop\rpd_script>python RdpConnect.pyo
  File "RdpConnect.pyo", line 1
SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xbd' in file RdpConnect.pyo on line
2, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for detail
s

Comment: I think the `*.pyo` file is not compatible with Windows or on a different architecture (32 bits / 64 bits). Can you check that? You may use a version a Python which is different than the one used to create the compiled file...

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE return same error on linux, 32/64 bits

Comment: Can you dump the first two bytes of you file. It must be a valid magic number. A list is available in https://github.com/google/pytype/blob/master/pytype/pyc/magic.py